# file_get_content can't load the content of websites

Tags: load, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

Since nobody give answer in my previous questions, I will reask this question:

I am trying to build a web crawler that targets specified web sites using **simple_html_dom**.  I've tried to load the content of such a web site categories using several methods already: **load_file, file_get_content, file_get_html, str_get_html,** but it keeps giving me a "not found" message like this:

```
"Check your spelling
Use another word or term similar to what you are looking for.
It is better if you use just one key word for searching.
Generally used keywords will give better result."
```

It is as if my code tries to load the empty search (with no keyword).  When I copied the url directly into the browser, I see the contents and elements I want.
Does this mean that there is a web site whose content can't be loaded by **simple_html_dom** methods?

Here is my testing code:

```
  include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

  $target_url = "http://www.zalora.co.id/women/sepatu/";

  $html = new simple_html_dom();
  $html -> load_file($target_url);

  //$html = file_get_html($target_url);

  //$html = file_get_contents($target_url);
  //$html = str_get_html($html);

  echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why you're getting this result, it seems very strange to me. I just tried to load the page html and it worked fine, though I use cURL. This is the code that I used:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.zalora.co.id/women/sepatu/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($curl_scraped_page, true, false);        
echo $html;
```

One other thing that I should say is that if you're looking to scrape prices from the page then you're out of luck. Take a look at the source code (right click on the page) and you'll see that the prices aren't visible. They're obviously trying to avoid being scraped. Unfortunately I don't know which alternative parsing tool you're going to have to employ to be successful.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will try your code. Yes, you are right, although there is price when I inspect element, but when I tried to view page source, the price does not lie in one of html element, but in var app. It means, they probably try to hide their value using Ajax or Json value. My code can't even access those products' link since they were hidden.

Comment: btw, I found another sites who just like this zalora, who avoid being scraped, and even worse, since there is no even link or value in view page source. They hide it in another "links" using ajax. So it means I need to access these links if I want to take their products value.

Comment: @RudyRaito let me know if you find another parser. I've just read about Selenium. Simple HTML Dom is a great beginners script, and I was a real beginner when I started to use it, but now I'm thinking of an upgrade.

Comment: I actually tried to combine simple html dom with PHPCrawl, but looks like it is the same. Yeah, we probably need another parser. It's great if we can make a script which can load website page like google chrome inspect element.

Comment: I found this in some websites: http://crawljax.com/, but crawljax.com is java-based crawler. There is another I found: http://scrapy.org/, it is phyton-based crawler. And there is also this: https://github.com/CalculatedContent/cloud-crawler, it is ruby-based crawler.

However since I am also a java user, I think I will try crawl-jax.